# Angular send object in ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, django, ng-file-upload

here its my angular code

```
                   Upload.upload({
                        url: '/designer/profile/projects_info/',
                        file: files,
                        fields: {projectInfo: $scope.projectInfo},
                    }).progress(function (evt) {
                        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                        // $scope.log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name + '\n' + $scope.log;
                    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $scope.projectUuid = data.projectUuid;
                        $scope.projectPicIdsList = [];
                        $scope.projectPicIdsList = data.projectPicIdsList;
                        // $timeout(function() {
                            // $scope.log = 'file: ' + config.file.name + ', Response: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\n' + $scope.log;
                        // });
                    });
```

I want to send my fields in upload function

```
fields: {projectInfo: $scope.projectInfo}
```

but It's not send in json format.

output of above code is

```
{u'projectInfo': [u'{"projectName":"abc","projectType":["xyz","abc"],"location":"pqr","projectDescription":"abcxyz"}']}>
```

but i want these object in json format not in string.

its my django view

```
def save_designer_projects_info(request):
    print request.POST
```

Comment: i use ng-flow too, but in console.log i have a json not a String (even if it let me see it as a String) can you write your server side application class?

Comment: @mautrok I got above output on server side....

Comment: ok the 'u' it's strange, i understand that this is the answer but the class that write the answer? can we see the code?

Comment: i have the server in java, but i think the problem is the same. when i send the response message i parse it into a json. Maybe you have allready done it but in this two rows i can't see that, could it be the problem?

Comment: Can you post here the browser's network tab request body that is being sent?